# "IO Error: Non-XML Content-Type: text/html" how can we fix this error?

Tags: xhtml

I am trying to check this page http://www.tightenzonline.com/santosh/index.htm for validation errors.

I am getting this error: "IO Error: Non-XML Content-Type: text/html"

http://validator.w3.org/nu/?charset=UTF-8&schema=http%3A%2F%2Fs.validator.nu%2Fw3c-xhtml5-microdata-rdfalite.rnc+http%3A%2F%2Fs.validator.nu%2Fhtml5%2Fassertions.sch+http%3A%2F%2Fc.validator.nu%2Fbase%2F+http%3A%2F%2Fc.validator.nu%2Fmicrodata%2F++http%3A%2F%2Fc.validator.nu%2Frdfalite%2F&parser=xml&doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tightenzonline.com%2Fsantosh%2Findex.htm

how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either:

1. Validate against a profile that doesn't require XML (such as XHTML 1.0 Transitional, which your document claims to be written in)
2. Configure your web server to serve the document with an XML media type (e.g. `application/xml`) in the HTTP Content-Type header
3. Click the *Be lax about content-type* option

I'd recommend option 1 if you are writing a web page intended for the general public.